# Is there a way how to see when somebody pushed on git?

Tags: git, gitlab

Is there some way to see the time of pushing?

tried to use git lg but it only shows when you commited.

Comment: No, this is not written anywhere *in git*. You might want to search for this information at other levels (network logs? your gitlab? other?)

Comment: Isn't the commit log the information you actually need though?  Can you elaborate on why you need to know when any given user pushed (or pulled)?

Comment: You can enable notifications for "push" in GitLab.  For example: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/emails_on_push.html.  Gitlab also allows you to configure a WebHook on "push events": https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhook_events.html#push-events